# Non-Accessible Recovery Mode on Mac

Tags: bootcamp, windows, recovery

I have a MacBook Pro (late 2011) and I'd like to install Windows 10 on it.

The best way to do it, is to use Boot Camp Assistant but not on my MacBook because it's not supported.

In order to change my MBR from Hybrid into Protective to be able to install Windows, I have to "disable csrutil" which is just available through recovery mode.

So here's the problem:
I can't access my Recovery mode.
I spent 5 hours waiting but it didn't come up

What should I do to access Recovery Mode easily?

Comment: You spent 5 hours holding Cmd/R ?? ...or, give us more detail...

Comment: no, after I held Cmd/R and the Apple Logo came up I left the keys and waited for the process to end and the Recovery mode to come up(which didn't :( )

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do not believe you need to enter what you refer to as Recovery Mode. If you the format either the 2nd, 3rd or 4th partition as MS-DOS(FAT), the partition method should change to hybrid.

You probably will not be able to install Windows 10 using a EFI boot method. You should use the legacy BIOS boot method. This means you want to use a hybrid partitioning scheme.

You should be able to download the "Boot Camp Support Software" (BCSS) using the Boot Camp Assistant. Although, for some Macs this download is the same as for a Windows 7 installation.

When running the Windows installer, you will need to reformat the MS-DOS(FAT) volume as NTFS.

Comment: So you mean I should boot the flash driver containing Windows 10 using the BIOS boot method?

Comment: Generally, a the 2011 and older Macs cannot boot the Windows installer from a  flash drive. Some users have reported their 2011 model  can indeed boot from a flash drive. Maybe your Mac is one of these exceptions. Whether you are using a flash drive or DVD to boot (by holding down the option key at startup), you need to choose the icon labeled "Windows". This will generate a BIOS boot. You will also have to install to a drive that hybrid partitioned. This means the partition you will be installing Windows on appears both in the GUID Partition Table (GPT)  and the MBR partition table.

Comment: Thanks but this helped: https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/3rzxd5/guide_windows_10_bootcamp_on_unsupported_macs/

Comment: @Mahshid: I read your posted link. Did this procedure work for your Mac? I ask because I  can see some obvious flaws. Also, does your optical (DVD) work? If not, then you should have included this fact in your posted question.

Comment: Yeah it totally worked out and I have both windows 10 and El Captain on my Mac now!
And about my Optical DVD Driver, it works and I never had any problems with it.